# SVN repo sync with TFS integrated Git

Tags: git, svn, visual-studio-2013, tfs, subgit

we have a bunch of teams happily using the integrated TFS Git repo in TFS 2013 and set up with CI/CD, but we have one team that's been off on their own for a while - they've only been using TFS for Work Item tracking and have been using a local SVN repo with local builds, manual QA and deploy etc.

They don't want to transition to Git (don't see the point) and are adamant they want to use SVN. Because all of our other teams use Git our standard TFS Team Project template sets up the Team Project to use integrated Git, so we can't use something like SVNBridge to link their SVN repo to the TFS version control without having to go through a lengthy process of creating new team projects and then using TFS Integration to move all of the work items (and history) across - a messy proposition at best.

What I'd like to do then is use something like SubGit to mirror the SVN repo into TFS integrated Git - but all of the SubGit documentation refers to a local Git repo which gets created as part of the SubGit config - I'd want it instead to use the already existing TFS integrated Git repo that relates to the existing Team Project.

I'm open to any suggestions around the best way to attack this conundrum - given the team MUST use SVN and the CI/CD build system MUST be in TFS (preferably using integrated Git as the TFS repo) what's the best way to get sync and automated CI working?

Comment: You can use SubGit with existing Git repository: `subgit configure --svn-url SVN_URL GIT_REPO`, adjust configuration and then run `subgit install GIT_REPO`. I guess `GIT_REPO` is empty in your case, so all SVN revisions gets imported to that Git repository and then two-way sync gets established. Just make sure that TFS properly triggers pre-receive and post-receive hooks when one pushes commits to Git repository, SubGit heavily relies on those hooks in order to mirror changes.

Comment: Thanks vadishev. The SVN repository is VisualSVN so I'll be following http://blog.subgit.com/visualsvn-subversion-server-and-git/. If I install SubGit on the SVN server and use the subgit configure --svn-url command to point to the existing TFS Integrated Git repo can I use SubGit in Local mode to get automatic sync?

Comment: Hi m455954, did we recently discuss this problem via support@subgit.com? If so I can publish an answer based on results of our discussion.